# How to calculate time difference of specific rows in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with timestamps for the sighting of different species.
I would like to calculate the difference in time between each sighting of SpeciesB and the last sighting of SpeciesA.

```
    df <- data.frame (Date.Time = c("2020-03-12 13:21:46", "2020-03-12 15:38:57", 
                            "2020-03-13 01:42:49", "2020-03-13 06:04:56", 
                            "2020-03-13 06:57:25", "2020-03-13 12:58:07"),
              (Species = c("SpeciesA", "SpeciesC", "SpeciesB", "SpeciesB", "SpeciesA", "SpeciesB")))
```

So I would like to achieve a column, that tells me for each sighting of SpeciesB how many minutes ago SpeciesA was sighted. For this example my desired result would be:

```
difftime = c("NA", "NA", "741.05", "1003.167", "NA", "360.7")
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this? I tried to use the mutate function and I have tried an ifelse statement without success.
Could you please help me? Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work for you, please let me know.

I unpivoted the data and then did a if_else column that calculated the time difference if Species B was seen.

To transfer it back to its orginal form we can unpivot and the filter out the excess NAs. (there may be a more efficient way to do this but the below works).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   mutate(id=row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = "Species",values_from = Date.Time) %>% 
   mutate(SpeciesA_fill=SpeciesA) %>%
   fill(SpeciesA_fill) %>% 
   mutate(delta_to_speciesA=if_else(!is.na(SpeciesB),difftime(SpeciesB,SpeciesA_fill,units = "mins"),NA_real_)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:4,names_to = "Species",values_to="Date.Time") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Date.Time)) %>% 
  select(-SpeciesA_fill)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @alejandro_hagan , it does work! As I want to do further calculations with the resulting "delta_to_speciesA"  could you also please help me to add it as a column in the original dataframe? I have never used pivot tables before.

Comment: I understand you want the data to go back to its original structure, is that right?

Comment: Yes thats right @alejandro_hagan

Comment: does the above work? @falafelmakali